# Self Join in Grouping Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

> PERSON_REF, CODE_START_DATE, CODE

where the `PK` is `PERSON_REF`

I want a query giving me those records where the `CODE_START_DATE` is in August 2012 together with the record with the latest `CODE_START_DATE` Prior to this, ie this pseudocode

```
SELECT PERSON_REF,
       CODE_START_DATE,               --S/B in August 2012
       CODE,
       CODE_START_DATE [PrevDate],    --Latest CODE_START_DATE Prior to Column 2 in Query
       CODE [PrevCode]                --Code at Date of Column 4 in Query
```

Columns 4 and 5 might be blank, in the case where there is no record prior to the column2 date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using **SQL Server**, give a try to *outer apply*. Here's the query

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.CODE_START_DATE PrevDate, T2.CODE PrevCode
FROM TableName T1 
 OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 1 *
     FROM TableName T2
     WHERE T2.CODE_START_DATE < T1.CODE_START_DATE 
     ORDER BY T2.CODE_START_DATE DESC
) T2
WHERE T1.CODE_START_DATE BETWEEN '01/Aug/12' AND '01/Sep/12'
```

**UPDATE:**

I've added where condition for rows in *August 2012*

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Below Query :

```
SELECT A.PERSON_REF,
       A.CODE_START_DATE,
       A.CODE,
       (Select Top 1 B.CODE_START_DATE From YourTable B Where B.CODE_START_DATE > A.CODE_START_DATE Order by CODE_START_DATE DESC)AS [PrevDate],
       (Select Top 1 B.CODE From YourTable B Where B.CODE_START_DATE > A.CODE_START_DATE Order by CODE_START_DATE DESC) AS [PrevCode]
From YourTable A
Where ..Conditions...
```